# ASP.NET Force IE8 to use IE7 or IE8 Compatability View

Tags: asp.net, ie8-compatibility-mode

I've tried the following and all it does is change the Document Mode, not the Browser Mode:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7">

<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7">
```

My particluar page only works when the browser mode is either IE7 or IE8 Compat View.

Comment: Suggestion: It's time to move forward, use the `html` doc-type and write code for modern browsers. And then you can go back and fix little nuances in older browsers by providing alternate stylesheets\overrides.

Comment: Agree completely. However this is for a CMS page that only a few admin users of the site will see, and the issue is regarding CKEditor.

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted should work.

Please ensure the following:

1. The meta tag is right at the top of the header, as first element after the `<title></title>`.
2. Restart IE and open your page without manually setting the Browser- or Document Mode from the Developer Tools. Setting these manually can overwrite IE's behavior and causes it to ignore the compatibility tag.

Comment: Turn it off and on again? ;) I've checked both points, however it is still only setting the Document Mode.

Comment: @JamieCarruthers: Oh, I fear you might not be able to force IE8 into a certain Browser Mode. Only the Document Mode is affected by a combination of the `X-UA-Compatible` meta tag and `DOCTYPE`, whereas the Browser Mode is AFAIK determined by IE itself, probably depending on your markup and other unknown factors.